# React fast global redux-like variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm making a front-end application using react/webgl and I need to be vary of performance improvements since almost everything must be rendered real-time and dynamically.

I need to render something on a canvas and need to use some variable's globally across many different components, but they need to be updated fast. Technically redux is what I need, however accessing dispatched variables takes time and causes crucial performance issues.

So instead I opted in to use useRef() which solves the “slow” issue but now I cannot update it’s value across different components. Using `useRef()` solves my issue but since it's not globally accessible it causes problems on other parts of the application.

**Declaration of the variable looks like this:**

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';

const WebGLStarter = (props) => {
    ...
    const myValue = useRef();

    myValue.current = someCalculation();

    function render(myValue.current){
       ...
       requestAnimationFrame(function () {
         render(myValue.current);
       });
    }

    ...
  
}
```

Currently `someCalculation()` is on the same component as it's declaration. I want to use `someCalculation()` on a different file but I can't do it beacuse `useRef()` won't allow me to. And again, I can't use redux because it's slow.

*TL;DR* : I need something similar to redux but it needs to be fast enough to not cause performance issues on an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) with the ref. Wrap your root with the provider, and use the hook to get access to the ref when you need to use/update it:

```
import { createContext, useRef, useContext } from 'react';

const defaultValue = /** default value **/;

const MyValueContext = createContext(defaultValue);

const MyValueContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const myValueRef = useRef(defaultValue);
  
  return (
    <MyValueContext.Provider value={myValueRef}>
      {children}
    </MyValueContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useMyValue = () => useContext(MyValueContext);
```

To use in components call the `useMyValue` hook. This would give you direct access to the ref, and since you don't update any state (just change the ref's `current` property) it won't cause re-renders:

```
const WebGLStarter = (props) => {
  const myValue = useMyValue();

  myValue.current = someCalculation();

  ...
};
```